# "Ficar feliz da vida" e formas de o dizer :)

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Gostaria de saber o que significa: **"Ficar feliz da vida"**. Eu ouvi muitas vezes esta frase e parace-me que está a dizer: **"Fiquei feliz demais"**. Isto está certo?

Comment: As pessoas ao meu redor, comigo incluso, usamos bastante essa frase, mas mais ironicamente e via piada. Sempre vi ela sendo usada com o sentido que descreveste, de ficar muitíssimo feliz.

Comment: Recentemente houve um sucesso vindo de Angola para expressar isto, com um bocado de ritmo fica [*"A felicidade"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mDPJ3PbiDo). Ou simplesmente *Felicidade* :)

Comment: Seria mais fácil com contexto, por exemplo _lá ia eu feliz da vida, quando X_ ou _voltou de lá feliz da vida_. Mas groso modo significa _contente_ ou _descontraído_: não tem a mesma carga que _feliz_ geralmente tem.

Comment: Obrigado. Alguem quiser deixar uma reposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu diria que geralmente significa "ficar **muito contente**", tanto em pt-BR quanto em pt-PT (me baseando no comentário de Artefacto).

Answer (score 2):

É uma expressão muito comum em pt-BR e que *geralmente* define **um estado de felicidade causado por um evento/fato/notícia/acontecimento/ocorrência.**

- "Ela ficou feliz da vida quando soube ter sido aprovada em primeiro lugar."
- "Ele ficou feliz da vida ao ler a carta do filho."
- "Eu nunca o tinha visto assim. Estava feliz da vida com a vitória do Porto sobre o Benfica."  (no Rio de Janeiro substitua por Vasco da Gama/Flamengo)

Contudo, nem sempre há um fator causal óbvio.

- "Ele não me pareceu estar sofrendo com a separação.  Pelo contrário, parecia feliz da vida.